# Designing a virtual memory with TLB

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, tlb

I've been given the following problem and I'm not sure exactly how to approach it:

> Consider a virtual memory system with the following properties:
>
> ·         35-bit virtual address
>
> ·         16 KB pages
>
> ·         32-bit physical address
>
> Assume that this virtual memory system is implemented with an
>   eight-way set  associative TLB. The TLB has total of 256 TLB entries,
>   with each TLB entry  representing one virtual-to-physical page number
>   translation.
>
> A 64 KB data cache is a two-way set associative cache. The data
>   cache’s  block size is 128 Bytes.
>
> Show the virtual to physical mapping with a figure drawn in a way
>   similar  to the figure below (but with all necessary changes required
>   for the TLB  and the data cache specified in this question).
>
> Specify the width of all fields and signals coming in and out of (as
>   well  as the number of comparisons done by) the TLB and the data cache
>   for  each memory address.

I sort of have an idea on how to compute some parameters, but otherwise, I'm lost.

For instance, since the virtual address is 35-bits wide, I know that I have 2^35 possible virtual addresses.

Since I have 16KB pages (16*1KB = 2^4 * 2^10 = 2^14KB), I know that I must have (3^35)/(2^14) = 2^21 page table entries.

Finally, I know that my cache size is 64 * 1KB = 2^16 bytes of cache.

But I am lost after these steps. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Figure]

Comment: Sorry, is the virtual address 32 bits wide or 35 bits?

Comment: 35 bits. I know, it's awkward

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I now noticed my typo. Fixed

Comment: Cross-posted on ComputerScience.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18313/755

Comment: @D.W. This was my older question as I previously mentioned at the cs stack exchange (before editing it for clarity as you suggested). Now that I have a better understanding of this topic, I felt it was necessary to post a new version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page offset is composed of the bits that address within a page and are not translated by the TLB.  With 16 KiB pages, the page offset would be 14 bits.

With a 35-bit virtual address, this leaves 21 bits to index a set in the TLB and tag entries in that set. Since the TLB has 256 entries and each set has eight entries (8-way associative), there are 32 sets, requiring 5 bits to index a set. This leaves 16 bits for the tag.

The size of the physical page number is equal to the size of the physical address minus the size of the page offset: 32 - 14 = 18 bits.

Illustrating a TLB that is neither direct-mapped nor fully associative is more complex than the example fully associative TLB as such adds a dimension of set indexing. This can be handled by overlaying ways so that one way (indexed dimension) is fully visible. Here is an ASCII art version for a 4-way structure with 8 entries per way:

```
               +----------+----------+
             +----------+----------+ |  
           +----------+----------+ |-+
         +----------+----------+ |-+ |
         |          |          |-+ |-+
         +----------+----------+ |-+ |
         |          |          |-+ |-+
         +----------+----------+ |-+ |
         |          |          |-+ |-+
         +----------+----------+ |-+ |
         |          |          |-+ |-+
         +----------+----------+ |-+ |
         |          |          |-+ |-+
         +----------+----------+ |-+ |
         |          |          |-+ |-+
         +----------+----------+ |-+ |
         |          |          |-+ |-+
         +----------+----------+ |-+
         |          |          |-+
         +----------+----------+
```

For 32 sets, one may wish to use ellipsis (...) to imply most of them. Similarly, ellipsis can be used to imply entries within a way (rather than having to draw hundreds of them).

For the cache, assuming a 4 byte access, the byte offset would be 2 bits. The block offset is used to index a 4-byte chunk within the cache block. With 128-byte cache blocks, indexing a specific byte would require 7 bits, so indexing a 4-byte chunk would only require 5 bits.

A 2-way associative 64 KiB will have 32 KiB in each way. With 128-byte cache blocks, this means that each way will have 256 blocks, so 8 bits of the physical address — beyond the block and byte offsets — are needed to index the specific set (cache block within each way). This is the cache index.

Given a 32-bit physical address, 8 bits of cache index, 5 bits of block offset, and 2 bits of byte offset, the tag will be 17 bits (32 - 8 - 5 - 2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's somewhat clearer now. however, the diagram I provided is fully-associative, not direct (It has a comparator for every block in the TLB).

Comment: @audiFanatic Ah, I did not notice that it was fully associative; I should have paid more attention. Anyway, which dimension one wishes to hide is somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: +1 for the 3D Ascii art, looking forward to someone asking about DRAM structure :)